# ARKIT application crashing with iOS version 11.2.5

Tags: ios, iphone, arkit

I have an AR application developed using ARKIT it is working fine with iOS Version 11.2.2. When the OS is upgraded to 11.2.5 the application launches correctly. In the ARView it is able track the surface and place the object correctly. However if any UI interaction like rotate, move etc is done in the ARView the application crashes. 
Note: Device used is Iphone 6S with iOS version 11.2.5 
Any inputs on this will be really helpful

Comment: Do you any crashing details like logs etc.?

Comment: In my case, Debug works fine but Release doesn't. iOS 11.3.1.